# Some queries regarding fetch strategies in hibernate and relation of fetchtype with fetchmode?

Tags: java, hibernate, fetching-strategy

I have gone thru some of the links for hibernate fetch strategies on net.One brief and concise link i liked is 
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/. We have four type of fetch strategies. these are :-

1. fetch-”join” = Disable the lazy loading, always load all the collections and entities.
2. fetch-”select” (default) = Lazy load all the collections and entities.
3. batch-size=”N” = Fetching up to ‘N’ collections or entities, *Not record*.
4. fetch-”subselect” = Group its collection into a sub select statement.

My first question which one of the above qualifies for eager or lazyloading fetch type?

To raise  my queries about  hibernate fetch strategies the i am considering below code snippet in my Department class

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,      orphanRemoval = true)
 @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
 @BatchSize(size = 10)
 private Set<EmployeeData> employees = new HashSet<EmployeeData>();
```

As per my understanding  As soon as i mention fetchtype as eager, i am left only with join fetch strategy but when i mention as fetchtype as lazyloading, i have 
other three options i.e select,batch-size and subselect.**Agreed?** Now if i look at code  snippet in one my legacy project , it mentioned fetch type as eager and fetch strategy
as select  which contracdicts each other. Right?

Another query is **i do not see batch-size option** when i write FetchMode. and do control + space in eclipse though i see other three fetch strategies?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hibernate collections have fetch type and fetch mode settings.

Fetch type specifies *when* elements of collection are retrieved, and fetch mode specifies *how* Hibernate retrieves them.

So, `FetchMode.SELECT` and `FetchMode.SUBSELECT` are legal with both `FetchType.EAGER` and `FetchType.LAZY`. The difference is that with `FetchType.EAGER` an additional select query is executed immediately, whereas with `FetchType.LAZY` it's executed after the first access to the collection.

`FetchMode.JOIN`, however, doesn't make sense with `FetchType.LAZY`.

Batch size is an additional optimization for `FetchMode.SELECT`, so that it should be configured by its own annotation (`@BatchSize`) and has nothing to do with `FetchMode` enumeration itself.

**See also:**

- [21.1. Fetching strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching)

Comment: Amazing and quick clarification

Answer (score 0):

The **batch-size=N** is almost equal to the **fetch=subselect**. Let me explain you how does it so:

Suppose you have 10000 parent records and each one of them have 500 child records, and if you use the fetching strategy as **subselect** then this is how the queries would look like:

**Subselect:**
Select * from parent;
select * from child where child.Parent_Id in(select Parent_Id from Parent).

**Note:** Just in case if the IN clause exceeds the limit which is provided by the underlying data base, obviously the above query fails. Here is the situation where the **batch-size** coming into the picture. By using **batch-size** we can mention number of Parent_Id's to be participated in the IN clause.

**Select & batch-size:**
Select * from parent;
select * from child where child.Parent_Id in(1,2,3,4......till the IN clause limit of the underlying DB).
select * from child where child.Parent_Id in(1001,1002......till the IN clause limit of the underlying DB).

**Note:** 
**batch-size** should be used with **fetch=select**, but not with **fetch=subselect**(since it doesn't make any sense).